# About a bunch of edits of old questions

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Over the last couple of days I've accepted [a lot of edits by the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1845869/james-mohler?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Obviously he searches posts having "help" in their titles and makes better titles. Each of his edits is, in my opinion, a good one. But I simply have a doubt I'd like to discuss, before I go on accepting his edits:

Do we really want to "touch" all those old (and often bad) questions? Wouldn't it be better to let them be forgotten?

Comment: Something wrong with the link you provided.

Comment: @m0nhawk Oops. I should check when copy-pasting links. I fixed it.

Comment: Some of them seem too minor indeed. But those can be judged as one normally would. The question's age doesn't really play a role there.

Comment: John Saunders is going to have a cow if he sees those edits, which didn't even remove tags from the title.

Comment: related: [Is this considering appropriate editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152572/182513)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Stack Overflow wasn't the high-volume site it is, I might object to too many old questions being edited because they would flood the front page and drown out all the new material. (Something which might be a problem on some of the lower traffic sites within the network) But I hardly ever see that being a problem.

So I would say, if the edits are good and complete (that is, not too minor) by all means accept them. If the content gets improved, that will only make the site as a whole better.

Comment: lol, careful what you say. [I sent a user on an editing mission](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142331/155826) a few months back, and encountered discussions regarding how said user had come to actually flood the homepage with edits. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 I told you retagging every question with `[computer]` was going to be a bad idea ;)

Comment: lol, It wasn't quite *that* extreme @jonsca, but this particular user was determined to get his Archaeologist badge, and that he did, despite me crawling back later on to write a retraction to my answer! :)  In this case, Bart gave a good rule of thumb. Just treat them like any other suggested edit.

Comment: @jmort253 Ha, by no means did I want to indicate that a user should go in and blindly edit old questions at a rapid pace. Of course (and I'm sure you understand) I'm merely arguing that we don't need to reject correct edits, just because they are made on old question.

Comment: Sure @Bart, I think you're tackling a different problem. ;)